# Remove all file in a folder minus one zipped file

Tags: linux, bash

How can I remove all files in one folder minus one file (.zip) from the command line? I am using bash to ssh to my server where I want to do this. I know I could use `rm -rf *` being in that folder, but I need to keep the zipped file as that contains all the new files to replace the others. How can I do this from the command-line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ rm -fr !(*.zip)
```

**`info "(bash) Pattern Matching"`**

```
   If the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin, several extended pattern matching  opera‐
   tors are recognized.  In the following description, a pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns sep‐
   arated by a |.  Composite patterns may be formed using one or more of the following sub-patterns:

          ?(pattern-list)
                 Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
          *(pattern-list)
                 Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
          +(pattern-list)
                 Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
          @(pattern-list)
                 Matches one of the given patterns
          !(pattern-list)
                 Matches anything except one of the given patterns
```

Comment: I cannot find a manual entry for shopt. `$ man shopt
No manual entry for shopt` So I guess I do not have it on my OSX using Bash.

Comment: The OS can be a pretty important tag as the shell varies so much.  I retagged your question for you, but try to be as specific as possible.

Comment: Never mind. Found it in man bash. Will see if it works on the server though. Not sure I can work with this a Dreamhost. They run Debian and Bash. PS Will add the OS tag the next time, but as I will try this a the hoster which runs Debian as well I should perhaps use Debian or Linux as tag

Comment: Sheesh... Make up your mind. :)

Comment: :) Sorry man. I will do it on Debian now, but if I can figure out how to do it on my Mac for future reference that will be cool too. Anyways, will try shortly. Zipped file is almost uploaded fully.

Comment: My answer above would work on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

`find . ! -name 'file.zip' -delete`

[man find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

Comment: This will also remove any subfolders and their contents.

Comment: Ok, I assumed based on the `-r` option to `rm` that this would be desired, but he could `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name 'file.zip' -delete`.  A good reason to sanity check any answer before copy/pasting into their shell. :)